# Trying to 3D print a birdhouse but need to identify plates

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I found a birdhouse on Thingiverse ([thing:1641240](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1641240)) I would like to print and build. It uses Lego plates for the floor and roof, but the problem is that the person that posted the design didn't include which Lego plates are used.

Here are the images from the files:

[image: birdhouse with Lego plates]

[image: birdhouse floor]

[image: birdhouse assembly]

[image: birdhouse parts]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The floor and ceiling aren’t one piece. They’re made of four [30357: Black Plate, Round Corner 3 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30357&in=S&colorID=11&ov=Y) each with an assortment of other square/rectangular plates to fill in the gaps.

It looks like there are 20 studs between the corner pieces on each side. The second image you posted shows a layer of tiles holding the floor together. Presumably there is another layer of offset plates holding the ceiling together from the bottom.

---

**Edit:**

Which pieces you select for the center of the floor/ceiling will come down to two factors:

1. Price, or how expensive they are to get (assuming you don't already have them).
2. Strength, or how easy it is to make a sturdy structure (assuming you aren't planning to glue them together).

Here's one possible tiling that favors strength:

[image]

And a layer of plates you could place on the underside to hold everything together:

[image]

In these examples, every joint on the first layer is overlapped by at least two studs on both sides by the second layer.

Here's the parts list for this tiling, along with the cheapest price on [bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) if you're buying each part from one buyer:

- (4 x $0.02) [Plate 1 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3623&name=Plate%201%20x%203&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (4 x $0.01) [Plate 1 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3666&name=Plate%201%20x%206&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (4 x $0.01) [Plate 2 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3021&name=Plate%202%20x%203&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (2 x $0.01) [Plate 2 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3795&name=Plate%202%20x%206&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (1 x $0.11) [Plate 2 x 14](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=91988&name=Plate%202%20x%2014&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (4 x $0.03) [Plate, Round Corner 3 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30357&name=Plate,%20Round%20Corner%203%20x%203&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (4 x $0.04) [Plate 4 x 8](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3035&name=Plate%204%20x%208&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (1 x $0.03) [Plate 6 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3958&name=Plate%206%20x%206&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (4 x $0.10) [Plate 6 x 10](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3033&name=Plate%206%20x%2010&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- (8 x $0.73) [Plate 6 x 12](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3028&name=Plate%206%20x%2012&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Total: $6.84

Remember to double this if you're building both the floor and ceiling with the same layout.

Comment: Presumably you could use 16x16 plates to fill the center and give a pretty stable base to add the corners onto.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the insights! Now I hate to be a pain, but I am not that familiar with all the different pieces available. Which other plates/pieces are being used? I can figure out the amounts, I just need to know which ones.

Comment: I added an example tiling, but it's really up to you. There's no right answer.

Comment: @DM Thank you very much! This gives me a direction to go in. I have installed BrickLink's Studio and am recreating the 2 designs.